# How to get statement which causes error 3609?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to find out which statement causes error `Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.`?

The code seems very straight-forward:

```
-- 1. Check 1
IF (EXISTS (
... check ...
   ))
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Does not allow 1', 16, 1);
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  RETURN;
END;

-- 2. Check 2
IF (EXISTS (
... check ...
   ))
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Does not allow 2', 16, 1);
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  RETURN;
END;
```

I have check if transaction exists, so I must not see that error after raised error.

**EDIT:**

I agree with you @gbn. I know that operation in the `TRIGGER` is one transaction.

The problem is that in our code (written by me and one colleague) there is a case in which `RAISERROR` does not rollbacks trigger. I see that in practive - the error is raised by the trigger but the new data is inserted. The syntax there was opposite - first `ROLLBACK` and then `RAISERROR`. I found that switching places will fix situation (I don't know why it works only in that way).

I decided to play a bit with `@@TRANCOUNT`. But when I inserted several trancount the trigger start giving me 3609. Removing `@@TRANCOUNT` did not fix the issue. Because I have `ROLLBACK` with check if there is open transaction 3609 is very strange for me. There is another trigger, but even if I disable it I still receive 3609.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use TRY/CATCH in the calling code and trigger, then the error handling process becomes a lot more predictable and reliable.

Without this, an error in the trigger (here caused by RAISERROR) *aborts the batch*. So you'll never see the error from RAISERROR.

See [Why TRY CATCH does not suppress exception in trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8693/why-try-catch-does-not-suppress-exception-in-trigger) for more

Note: a trigger is always in a transaction because it is part of the DML. Any trigger code/actions must be atomic with the DML of course.